# base64 convertion on server - NodeJS

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, base64

I'm building an API and I get an image uploaded in a post request , I need to convert it to base64 , I know how to convert an image to base64 using Buffer , but the problem is I don't get the image itself instead if I use multer I get an object with info about the image , and if I don't use it I get an empty request body , so I don't even have an image to convert , what should I do ?

Comment: If you are using `multer` with `memoryStorage` (as opposed to `diskStorage`), you will get the file as `Buffer` at `req.buffer`. If you want your image to be stored on disk as well, you can read the file using node `fs` module which can read file as `Buffer`

Comment: great ! , and after that how can I convert that buffer to a base64 code that I can decode on the front end to eventually have the photo on UI ?

Comment: You mentioned you knew how to convert an image to base64 using Buffer, you could use that approach. But on a side note, why would you want to convert from and to base64? If you have it on disk you can use express to serve it, are you planning to save it as base64 somewhere?

Comment: It just came into an error so I asked , but I figured it out now it's working great.
I needed to store it in my database , but now I think this will cost storage as it is really big , I think amazon s3 is the choice to consider now .
And I can't serve it via express because I'm using Heroku , it's ephemeral , static files are deleted when dynos restart

Comment: Ok, I just remember I commented on your other question. Object storage (S3, Google Cloud Storage, etc.) is a good way to store files. It'll be a lot cheaper and generally faster. If you still need to convert a buffer to base64 somehow, you can do `buffer.toString('base64')`

Comment: yes thank you that's how I did it , thanks a lot for helping me out on different questions